# How can i track that a mail is opened by the receiver or not using node js

Tags: node.js, heroku, mean-stack, nodemailer

I tried to use 1px,1px method but gmail blocks the response...
Can anyone help me to know that how can this be done...
I want to get the status that has the receiver opened the mail or not...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Simple steps you can follow to achieve this:

```
1. When you send a mail template add a js script in that
2. Call backend API from that script (using fetch)
3. Store the data in the database. (Request body)
```

Comment: Can you please give an example! How can i implement that..

Comment: @ShivamRajput I gave you complete steps, what you have to do.

Comment: Ok Will Try it!! :)